# Change header-body-separator with HttpURLConnection (from java.net)

Tags: java, http, post, httpurlconnection

I am sending a simple POST request with the built-in `HttpURLConnection` class, but I want to change the way Java separates the headers from the body (look at the outputs of `tcpflow -a port 80` below). Here is the code:

```
// Create HttpURLConnection object
URL url = new URL("http://httpbin.org/post");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Set request method
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

// Write body and "Content-Length" header
String body = "This+is+the+body+of+the+post+request.";
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
    String.valueOf(body.length()));
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.getOutputStream().write(body.getBytes("US-ASCII"));

// Send request
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

When I execute that code and look at what Java actually sends using `tcpflow -a port 80` (prints all requests/responses on port 80), I see the following (I cut away the response):

```
192.168.178.113.54654-054.225.177.165.00080: POST /post HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java/9
Host: httpbin.org
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 37


192.168.178.113.54654-054.225.177.165.00080: This is the body of the post request.
```

The headers are correct, the body is correct. But I can see that the body is transferred in a separate connection. I know that this is a problem with java.net.HttpURLConnection because when I try the same with Apache's HttpClient, `tcpflow -a port 80` gives me:

```
192.168.178.113.39708-054.243.202.193.00080: POST /post HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 37
Host: httpbin.org
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/9)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

This+is+the+body+of+the+post+request.
```

Here the body is sent with the headers, separated with just `/r/n/r/n`. I would like the Java library (`java.net.HttpURLConnection`) to do the same. Is that possible?

EDIT: I found out that the reason the server rejected my requests was not that the body was in a different packet (packet, not connection, as Julian Reschke pointed out) than the headers but just that I sent the wrong data *facepalm*.

Comment: I think you are misreading it. It's still the same connection, just a different TCP packet.

Comment: And there's no server which has problems with the body being in a different TCP packet?

Comment: Why do you think it would be a problem?

Comment: It's my impression that requests are usually sent like the Apache library does it, so couldn't it be possible that some server doesn't support the java.net.HttpURLConnection way?